# Qt push button is calling 2 slots and I only need one

Tags: c++, qt

I need to call a 2 functions with different buttons
I have this code:

```
signalMapperSelections = new QSignalMapper();

QPushButton *selected_type_button = new QPushButton();
selected_type_button->setObjectName("selected_type_button");
selected_type_button->setText(get_selected_type().replace(" ", "\n"));
selected_type_button->setMinimumHeight(80);
selected_type_button->setMinimumWidth(80);
selected_type_button->setMaximumHeight(80);
selected_type_button->setMaximumWidth(80);
selected_type_button->setStyleSheet(style_toolbutton);
ui->verticalLayout_selections->addWidget(selected_type_button);
connect(selected_type_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapperSelections, SLOT(map()));
signalMapperSelections->setMapping(selected_type_button, get_selected_type());
connect(signalMapperSelections, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), this, SLOT(show_brands(QString)));

QPushButton *selected_brand_button = new QPushButton();
selected_brand_button->setObjectName("selected_brand_button");
selected_brand_button->setText(get_selected_brand().replace(" ", "\n"));
selected_brand_button->setMinimumHeight(80);
selected_brand_button->setMinimumWidth(80);
selected_brand_button->setMaximumHeight(80);
selected_brand_button->setMaximumWidth(80);
selected_brand_button->setStyleSheet(style_toolbutton);
ui->verticalLayout_selections->addWidget(selected_brand_button);
connect(selected_brand_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapperSelections, SLOT(map()));
signalMapperSelections->setMapping(selected_brand_button, get_selected_brand());
connect(signalMapperSelections, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), this, SLOT(show_models(QString)));
```

When I click "selected_type_button" I only want to run "show_brands". But it's running both functions, "show_brands" and "show_models"...
I tried Qt::UniqueConnection, but it doesn't fix this problem.
I think this is happening because both buttons are using the same signal... But I don't know how to fix it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: any reason for using `QSignalMapper`? if you just want `signal_type_bytton` to trigger `show_brands()` and `signal_brand_button` to trigger `show_models()`, there is no need to use `QSignalMapper` at all.

Comment: Currently, both buttons trigger the `map()` slot, which emits the `mapped` signal. Since the latter is connected to both slots `show_models` and `show_brands`, they are both invoked when either one of the buttons is clicked, I guess this is not how `QSignalMapper` is meant to be used. Please describe what exactly you want to do, and what is the `QString` argument you are passing to the slots meant for

Comment: QString is the selected type or selected brand....

Comment: this buttons are my previous selections... so, whenever I click one of them, I want to show different informations. if I click "selected_type_button" I want to run "show_brands" or "selected_brand_button" I want to run "show_models"... but when I click one I run both functions

Comment: I fixed it this using different QSignalMappers...

Comment: I guess you are doing something wrong,  I think that this will not give you the `QString` arguments you are expecting (if you want to get the selected type/brand at the time of the button click). Read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> When I click "selected_type_button" I only want to run "show_brands".

There is no reason to use `QSignalMapper` in your situation at all. You just have to connect `clicked` signal from `selected_type_button` to the `show_brands` slot, and `clicked` signal from `selected_brand_button` to the `show_models` slot.

> QString is the selected type or selected brand....

This `QString` argument has nothing to do with the `clicked` signal's source (So, it does not need any mapping using `QSignalMapper`, read about `QSignalMapper` in the docs [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html#details)). The mapping you are currently using is set up at the connection time (not at emit time) , this means that `get_selected_type()`/`get_selected_brand()` will return the selected items at the time of calling `setMapping` (this is obviously not what you meant).

To get the item at the time of clicking the button, you can call your `get_selected_type()`/`get_selected_brand()` functions in your slots directly, your code will be something like this:

```
QPushButton *selected_type_button = new QPushButton();
selected_type_button->setObjectName("selected_type_button");
selected_type_button->setText(get_selected_type().replace(" ", "\n"));
selected_type_button->setMinimumHeight(80);
selected_type_button->setMinimumWidth(80);
selected_type_button->setMaximumHeight(80);
selected_type_button->setMaximumWidth(80);
selected_type_button->setStyleSheet(style_toolbutton);
ui->verticalLayout_selections->addWidget(selected_type_button);
//Qt 5 new connect syntax (replace ClassName with the current class's name)
connect(selected_type_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &ClassName::show_brands);

QPushButton *selected_brand_button = new QPushButton();
selected_brand_button->setObjectName("selected_brand_button");
selected_brand_button->setText(get_selected_brand().replace(" ", "\n"));
selected_brand_button->setMinimumHeight(80);
selected_brand_button->setMinimumWidth(80);
selected_brand_button->setMaximumHeight(80);
selected_brand_button->setMaximumWidth(80);
selected_brand_button->setStyleSheet(style_toolbutton);
ui->verticalLayout_selections->addWidget(selected_brand_button);
//replace ClassName with the current class's name)
connect(selected_brand_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &ClassName::show_models);
```

and your `show_brands` slot should look something like:

```
//no need for the QString argument
void ClassName::show_brands(){
    QString selectedType= get_selected_type();

    //show_brands here
}
```

the same thing for `show_models` slot:

```
void ClassName::show_models(){
    QString selectedBrand= get_selected_brand();

    //show_models here
}
```